# Validation using regular expression to accept only character and spaces but no leading numbers in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation

So I have written a regular expression for a textchanged event in textbox, everything is going smooth, but when I am adding numeric values after character or spaces it hangs my project and sometimes I can add numeric values after chars but when I press backspace it hangs my project completely! no error nothing appears then!

here is my code:

```
 Private Sub txtbook_name_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbook_name.TextChanged
    Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^([a-zA-Z]*( *)?)*$")
    If (regex.IsMatch(txtbook_name.Text)) Or txtbook_name.Text = "" Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtbook_name, String.Empty)
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtbook_name, "Please enter valid Character")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to only have letters at the beginning of the string and later any amount of any letters? You need to rewrite the regex and exact requirements are necessary. If you need to only accept *letters* and *spaces*, you can just use `^\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*$` (this will also disallow leading and trailing spaces). To allow an empty string: `^(\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*)?$`

Comment: Or perhaps just `^[a-zA-Z ]*$`?

Comment: add `try catch` to identify your error

Comment: The error is clear: it is catastrophic backtracking. The requirements are not clear.

Comment: @stribizhev I am not that expert in regex, So I went for the second option because it is more clear and readable ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you came across is called *catastrophic backtracking*. See your [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX4aJ1/1) reproducing the issue. This happens because there are several optional subpatterns that as such can match the same substring, and the longer the input string, the more combinations a regex engine must check before admitting there is no match.

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

This regex will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z ]*` - 0 or more characters that are ASCII letters or a regular space (to match all whitespace, use `\s` and to match all Unicode letters, use `\p{L}\p{M}`)
- `$` - end of string